# SQLAlchemy does not generate sequence for primary key field

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```
class GeoLocation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "geolocations"
    id = Column(SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    coordinates = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
```

Using SQLAlchemy 0.9.8 and postgresql 9.3.6 it produces the right create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE geolocations (
        id SMALLSERIAL NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
        coordinates VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

On another machine, same SQLAlchemy version but with postgresql 9.1.13 it does not, producing:

```
CREATE TABLE geolocations (
        id SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
        coordinates VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Seem that the difference in in the support for the smallserial datatype. This is not available for postgres 9.1.13:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html